# Necesito colorear al azar una figura

Tags: javascript

Para que la figura cambie de color cada vez que vuelve a generarse, se sugiere crear un arreglo “var color” con al menos 5 colores. Luego crear una variable que permite generar un número al azar entre 0 y la longitud del arreglo menos 1. Además, para que la figura con relleno cambie de color, en vez de usar “`ctx.strokeStyle`” deberás utilizar “`ctx.fillStyle`”.(JavaScript)

```
  var color = ["Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"];
      var randcolor = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)-1];
ctx.fillStyle = "";
```

Necesito si alguien me puede revisar la sintaxis, y si me pueden decir como puedo hacer para que ctx.fillStyle use randcolor. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que en el random tienes el fallo

```
// Mi array de colores
var color = ["Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"];
// Numero al azar para el color (saca de 0 a n-1)
// Lo que se necesito para el array !!
NumAleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * color.length));
// Recojo el Color del Array
ColorAleatorio = color[NumAleatorio];
ctx.fillStyle = ColorAleatorio;
```

```js
// Mi array de colores
var color = ["Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"];
// Numero al azar para el color (saca de 0 a n-1)
// Lo que se necesito para el array !!
NumAleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * color.length));
// Recojo el Color del Array
ColorAleatorio = color[NumAleatorio];
var c = document.getElementById("MiCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = ColorAleatorio;
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="MiCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    </canvas>
```